# Help me identify the literary device (if any)

Tags: figures-of-speech, literary-device

Is there a literary device hidden in the following sentence?

> The officer wheels me around

I was thinking if it could be a hyperbole or a trope opposite to personification, because a person does not have "wheels".

Comment: There is no literary device there.

Comment: Please provide more information. If you're on a cart and the officer is moving you around, then that's wheeling, no figure of speech. If he's turning you, again that's a standard dictionary definition. But there are more metaphorical usages of "to wheel".

Comment: @StuartF "_...more metaphorical usages of " to wheel"._? Could you reference such usages please?

Comment: @405  Any usage (hopefully not _too_ fanciful) where literal wheels are not involved is by definition metaphorical. _The flock of starlings suddenly wheeled towards the lighthouse. / Jim wheeled on Jill and began to shout at her._